# Hibernate 3.5 @OneToMany annotation and PostgreSQL

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, entity-relationship

I have a table called article with the following columns in the below order:

article table:

1)creator_id
2)article_id(pk)
3).....

article_page table:

1)article_page_id(pk)
2)article_page_number
3)article_id(fk --> article table ).

Im using either unidirectional or bidirectional hibernate annotation mapping and the following problem occurs when i'm trying to save an article object that has many article_page objects calling save():

The article is inserted in the table article and a new article_id is generated. But when trying to insert rows in the article_page table hibernate is trying to use the creator_id from the table article instead of the article_id.

I have double checked my java annotated classes and I don't seem to find any mistake. I was wondering if creator_id being in position 1 of the PostgreSQL article table causing this strange behavior. Or is it something else?

Comment: Order isn't important, there must be a problem with your annotations - can you post some of your code?

Comment: I tried a bit more using pure JDBC and not hibernate.

the getGeneratedKeys() call returns a resultSet which getInt(1) content is not my primary key column (article_id) but the column creator_id. Sounds like a postgresql issue to me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems that all the columns of my table article are considered auto-generated so they all get returned in the getGeneratedKeys() call. The order in which the columns exist in the table article is the order in which you can retrieve them form the GeneratedKeys. In our case my primary key is returned through getInt(2) since its the second in order.

Hibernate 3.5 as it seems retrieves as a primary key the first column.